# How to "parse" Azure resource id object with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am currently trying to pull data from an Azure policy for some automation with:

> (Get-AzPolicyState -Filter "ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant'" | Where-Object {$*.PolicyDefinitionReferenceId -eq "azure backup should be enabled for virtual machines_1"} | Where-Object {$*.SubscriptionId -eq "0000"}).ResourceId

Type Name: System.String

Example output

> /subscriptions/00/resourcegroups/rg-test/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/vm-test

> /subscriptions/00/resourcegroups/rg-test2/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/vm-test2

I am confused on how I can just pull the resource group name and virtual machine name only into a variable array.
The resource group name is always preceded by /resourcegroups/ and VM name is always preceded by /virtualmachines/.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `$rg,$vm= '/subscriptions/00/resourcegroups/rg-test/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/vm-test' -replace '^.*/resourcegroups/([^/]+)/.*virtualmachines/([^/]+)','$1/$2' -split '/'`

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved?

Comment: You could use Regex; e.g. `$resourceId -replace '^\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?.*', "Subscription: [\`$1]\`nResource Group: [\`$2]\`nResourceType: [\`$3]\`nName: [\`$4]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to extract your VM name and groupName from `resourceID`, just try the code below:

```
function parseGroupAndName{
     param (
        [string]$resourceID
    )
    $array = $resourceID.Split('/') 
    $indexG = 0..($array.Length -1) | where {$array[$_] -eq 'resourcegroups'}
    $indexV = 0..($array.Length -1) | where {$array[$_] -eq 'virtualmachines'}
    $result = $array.get($indexG+1),$array.get($indexV+1)
    return $result
}

$resourceID = '/subscriptions/00/resourcegroups/rg-test/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/vm-test'

parseGroupAndName -resourceID $resourceID
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hey Stanley, thanks for this! I am still a little confused on how I would scale this to the output from the Get-AzPolicyState as it outputs multiple strings of resource id. Would I use a foreach loop with the function to achieve this? Thanks a lot, pardon for the questions as I am new to powershell.

Comment: @EG92,Yes, if Get-AzPolicyState replies multiple strings, you can just use a foreach loop to do this. Let me know if you have any more questions.And If my post is helpful, pls mark it as an answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

more simple :

```html
$resourceID = '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/rrrrrrr/providers/aaaa/bbbb/nnnnn'
$cc=Get-AzResource -ResourceId 

$cc.ResourceType
aaaaa/bbbb

$cc.ResourceGroupName
rrrrrr

$cc.Name
nnnnnnn
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, all I need is the resource name. For that, the following code solves the trick:

```
$vmId.Split('/') | Select-Object -Last 1
```